# How to use MySql date format function in queryDsl

Tags: date-format, querydsl

code :

```
Expressions.stringTemplate("DATE_FORMAT({0},'%Y-%M-%D')",qMember.createdDate).eq(keyword)
```

but it throws:

```
[268, 317] The right expression is not a valid expression.
```

and the SQL print in console :

```
or DATE_FORMAT(member1.createdDate,'%Y-%M-%D') = ?2)
```

so why?